# is @Html.HiddenFor correct way to re-post displayed data from my view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm new to mvc and have what is no doubt a basic question.

I have a viewmodel that displays some fields as labels only.

When I post the form back however I still want my viewmodel to contain these details.

Is the correct way to go about doing this to have:

```
@Html.HiddenFor
```

for my value or is there a better/different industry standard way of doing this?

Comment: You can go with it.. It is a correct way of doing it. We can treat those values differently in case you are submitting for via AJAX.

Comment: OK thanks. What do you mean you'd treat them differently if submitting via ajax?

Comment: Yes we can, we can store those values in javascript and can send those with data object.

Comment: I can't mark your answer as correct...

Comment: Cheers :) not to worry, i haven't answers yet. and no need to post an answer.. i hope you got your answer though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, using the @Hidden.For is the correct way to post back a label value.

However, if you are looking this up in your get method you could always re-look it up in the post method assuming that the user cannot change the label value in some way in your UI.

Comment: In fact, I would strongly encourage re-querying the data if possible - relying on the client to POST the data back can be risky, depending on what the data is used for. Remember that it's possible (and quite easy) to construct a POST manually, and thereby enter whatever values you want for those hidden fields. If you're using any of those values for authorisation or authentication, you may have a security risk there.

Comment: @anaximander Yes, I totally agree with your comments, Upvoted.

Comment: The value being posted back is a guid used to re-query. Am I right in thinking that [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] would fix the risk you mention?

Comment: If you aren't persisting those POSTed elements, then I'd say just POST them as suggested if you can save a lookup for performance reasons.